# Process the internal build log in step

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to `grep` the build log to count the number of compiler warnings. Is it possible to run a command on the build log from this or previous step?

TeamCity Enterprise 2022.04.4 (build 108763)

Comment: you could try call TeamCity REST API from bash script to get current build status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get the run log from TeamCity. A bit of a roundabout way, but it works:

```
warning_count=$(curl https://<teamcity-server>/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=%teamcity.build.id% --user "%system.teamcity.auth.userId%:%system.teamcity.auth.password%" | grep -c 'warning: ')
```

It uses `curl` to get the log the same way the log is downloaded from the web UI. Then just pipe the result into `grep`.

A side bonus: the `warning_count` can be used to create a Statistics value:

```
echo "##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='warning_count' value='$warning_count']"
```

Answer (score 1):

The last answer inspired me to write something alike but using powershell.
Add a build step after GNU make has run with this script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "%system.teamcity.auth.password%" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("%system.teamcity.auth.userId%",$password)

# Tell Invoke-RestMethod to use Basic Authentication scheme with Rest-API credentials
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://<host_url>/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=%teamcity.build.id%" -Credential $credentials

$warningCount = ([regex]::Matches($response, "(?i)warning" )).count

# Set TeamCity status/statistic"
Write-Host
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildStatus text='{build.status.text}; Build warnings: $warningCount']"
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='warning_count' value='$warningCount']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save compiler's output to a file and then grep it. For example

```
make 2>&1 | tee make.log
grep -o 'WARN' make.log | wc -l
```

In that case `tee` prints command output to both stdout and file